# macOS: Security & Privacy preference pane in System Preferences is greyed out

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

Security & Privacy preference pane in System Preferences app is greyed out.  I read there should be a lock icon I can click on to unlock this setting, but I do not see the lock icon. How can I access the pane?

[image]

Comment: Are you using an Admin account, or Managed?

Comment: @Tetsujin is there a way I can check?

Comment: @Tetsujin in Users and Groups my account shows as "Admin, Managed, Mobile"

Comment: Do you own this computer yourself, or is it managed by your employer/school/Government agency?

Comment: If you open a Finder window and browse to the folder `System>Library>PreferencePanes>`, is there a file called `Security.prefPane`?